# Use html center tag with php echo

Tags: html

Is it possible to use the html center tag prior to a 'PHP echo' to center the PHP echo? I'm trying to center a php echo in an html table, align center and the html center don't seem to be having the desired effect onthe php echo...?

Example:

```
<td width="80"><label for="Usage"><center><?php echo $sum4 > 0 || $sum4!==null ? $sum4 : "0"; ?></center></label></td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Label is an inline element, whilst `center` is a block, which isn't semantic HTML. Try putting the `center` around the label. Also note that `center` is quite an old tag now.

Comment: Great info in the comment above. Only thing to add is you should use the `text-align: center;` css.

Comment: `<center>` is a deprecated tag.  While some browsers may still support it, you shouldn't be using it.  You probably want to use `text-align: center` on your `<td>` instead.

Comment: Thanks that did it. What tag should I be looking to use instead if center is considered old?

Comment: No alternative tag exist, but css rule "text-align:center;".

Comment: Does text-align: center in the td tag work in all browsers? I've been using Chrome and Safari an they seem fine with normal html center tag.

Comment: It is a CSS1 rule so yes (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Center` is a very old and deprecated tag.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Try with inline CSS:

```
<td width='80' style='text-align:center;'>
    <?php echo ($sum4 > 0 || $sum4! == null) ? $sum4 : '0'; ?>
</td>
```

or add the CSS to you stylesheet:

Head:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Body:

```
<td width='80' class='center'>
    <?php echo ($sum4 > 0 || $sum4! == null) ? $sum4 : '0'; ?>
</td>
```